# Can TOmniEventMonitor be used in a background thread?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, omnithreadlibrary

### Original Question

In our Delphi XE4 application we use a TOmniEventMonitor to receive messages from other tasks. As long as this is running in the main thread, it works fine, but once I put the same code in a task, the TOmniEventMonitor stops receiving messages. I have included a simple example of this below -- clicking Button_TestInMainThread results in a file being written as expected, clicking Button_TestInBackgroundThread does not. Is this by design, or is there some way to get this working while still using TOmniEventMonitor?

```
unit mainform;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages,
  System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics,Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  OtlTask, OtlTaskControl, OtlComm, OtlEventMonitor;

const
  MY_OMNI_MESSAGE = 134;

type
  TOmniEventMonitorTester = class(TObject)
    fName : string;
    fOmniEventMonitor : TOmniEventMonitor;
    fOmniTaskControl : IOmniTaskControl;
    constructor Create(AName : string);
    destructor Destroy(); override;
    procedure HandleOmniTaskMessage(const task: IOmniTaskControl; const msg: TOmniMessage);
  end;

  TTestLauncherTask = class(TOmniWorker)
    fOmniTaskMonitorTester : TOmniEventMonitorTester;
    function Initialize() : boolean; override;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button_TestInMainThread: TButton;
    Button_TestInBackgroundThread: TButton;
    procedure Button_TestInMainThreadClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button_TestInBackgroundThreadClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    fOmniEventMonitorTester : TOmniEventMonitorTester;
    fTestLauncherTask : IOmniTaskControl;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}


procedure OmniTaskProcedure_OneShotTimer(const task: IOmniTask);
begin
  Sleep(1000);
  task.Comm.Send(MY_OMNI_MESSAGE);
end;

constructor TOmniEventMonitorTester.Create(AName : string);
begin
  inherited Create();
  fName := AName;
  fOmniEventMonitor := TOmniEventMonitor.Create(nil);
  fOmniEventMonitor.OnTaskMessage := HandleOmniTaskMessage;
  fOmniTaskControl := fOmniEventMonitor.Monitor(CreateTask(OmniTaskProcedure_OneShotTimer)).Run();
end;

destructor TOmniEventMonitorTester.Destroy();
begin
  fOmniEventMonitor.Free();
  inherited Destroy();
end;

procedure TOmniEventMonitorTester.HandleOmniTaskMessage(const task: IOmniTaskControl; const msg: TOmniMessage);
var
  Filename : string;
  F : TextFile;
begin
  Filename := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFileDir(ParamStr(0))) + fName + '.txt';
  AssignFile(F, Filename);
  Rewrite(F);
  Writeln(F, fName);
  CloseFile(F);
end;

function TTestLauncherTask.Initialize() : boolean;
begin
  result := inherited Initialize();
  if result then begin
    fOmniTaskMonitorTester := TOmniEventMonitorTester.Create('background');
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button_TestInMainThreadClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fOmniEventMonitorTester := TOmniEventMonitorTester.Create('main');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button_TestInBackgroundThreadClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fTestLauncherTask := CreateTask(TTestLauncherTask.Create()).Run();
end;

end.
```

### Additional Observations

With the following code it seems to be possible to successfully use a TOmniEventMonitor within a background thread. This really is a very clumsy solution -- an IOmniTwoWayChannel gets created but not used in any meaningful way -- but as soon as I try to simplify the code by commenting out either of the lines marked "don't remove!", HandleTaskMessage doesn't get called any more. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here?

```
unit mainform;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages,
  System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  DSiWin32, GpLists, OtlTask, OtlTaskControl, OtlCommon, OtlComm, OtlEventMonitor;

const
  MY_OMNI_MESSAGE = 134;

type

  TOmniEventMonitorTestTask = class(TOmniWorker)
    fOmniTaskControl : IOmniTaskControl;
    fOmniTwoWayChannel : IOmniTwoWayChannel;
    fOmniEventMonitor : TOmniEventMonitor;
    function  Initialize() : boolean; override;
    procedure HandleTaskMessage(const task: IOmniTaskControl; const msg: TOmniMessage);
    procedure HandleTaskTerminated(const task: IOmniTaskControl);
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button_TestInBackgroundThread: TButton;
    procedure Button_TestInBackgroundThreadClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    fTestTask : IOmniTaskControl;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure OmniTaskProcedure_OneShotTimer(const task: IOmniTask);
begin
  Sleep(1000);
  task.Comm.Send(MY_OMNI_MESSAGE); // don't remove!
  (task.Param['Comm'].AsInterface as IOmniCommunicationEndpoint).Send(MY_OMNI_MESSAGE);
end;

procedure TOmniEventMonitorTestTask.HandleTaskMessage(const task: IOmniTaskControl; const msg: TOmniMessage);
var
  Filename : string;
  F : TextFile;
begin
  Filename := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFileDir(ParamStr(0))) + 'HandleTaskMessage.txt';
  AssignFile(F, Filename);
  Rewrite(F);
  Writeln(F, 'HandleTaskMessage!');
  CloseFile(F);
end;

procedure TOmniEventMonitorTestTask.HandleTaskTerminated(const task: IOmniTaskControl);
var
  Filename : string;
  F : TextFile;
begin
  Filename := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFileDir(ParamStr(0))) + 'HandleTaskTerminated.txt';
  AssignFile(F, Filename);
  Rewrite(F);
  Writeln(F, 'HandleTaskTerminated!');
  CloseFile(F);
end;

function TOmniEventMonitorTestTask.Initialize() : boolean;
begin
  result := inherited Initialize();
  if result then begin
    fOmniEventMonitor := TOmniEventMonitor.Create(nil);
    fOmniEventMonitor.OnTaskMessage := HandleTaskMessage;
    fOmniEventMonitor.OnTaskTerminated := HandleTaskTerminated;
    fOmniTwoWayChannel := CreateTwoWayChannel();
    Task.RegisterComm(fOmniTwoWayChannel.Endpoint1); // don't remove!
    fOmniTaskControl := fOmniEventMonitor.Monitor( CreateTask(OmniTaskProcedure_OneShotTimer) ).SetParameter('Comm', fOmniTwoWayChannel.Endpoint2).Run();
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button_TestInBackgroundThreadClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fTestTask := CreateTask(TOmniEventMonitorTestTask.Create()).Run();
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem with TOmniEventMonitor running inside of a thread, provided there is a message pump handling the messages for it. I put this block of code together to demonstrate. This works as expected.

```
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
  Message: TMsg;
begin
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  fOmniEventMonitor := TOmniEventMonitor.Create(nil);
  fOmniEventMonitor.OnTaskMessage := HandleOmniTaskMessage;
  fOmniTaskControl := fOmniEventMonitor.Monitor(CreateTask(OmniTaskProcedure_OneShotTimer)).Run();
  try
    while not Terminated do
    begin
      if MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(0, nil^, False, 1000, QS_ALLINPUT) = WAIT_OBJECT_0 then
      begin
        while PeekMessage(Message, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) do
        begin
          TranslateMessage(Message);
          DispatchMessage(Message);
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    fOmniTaskControl := nil;
    fOmniEventMonitor.Free;
  end;
end;
```

From what I can see, the TOmniTaskExecutor waits for messages to specific handles. In your code example, it's the terminate event and a couple of comm handles. The messages for the TOmniEventMonitor are never processed.

Changing your `TTestLauncherTask.Initialize` to the following results in it correctly writing out the file. `DoNothingProc` is just an empty method on the class.

```
function TTestLauncherTask.Initialize() : boolean;
begin
  result := inherited Initialize();
  if result then begin
    fOmniTaskMonitorTester := TOmniEventMonitorTester.Create('background');
    // Tell the task about the event monitor
    Task.RegisterWaitObject(fOmniTaskMonitorTester.fOmniEventMonitor.MessageWindow, DoNothingProc);
  end;
end;
```

I am adding the message window for the TOmniEventMonitor to the Task WaitObject list so the handle is then registered with the `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` call and waiting for Remi and David to tear my message handling to shreds :)

Comment: Thanks, that works :) Maybe I should wait a day or two before accepting the answer to see if others comment on this?

Comment: @Tim Up to you. I don't mind. The question has been open for quite a while but it would be nice if someone like Remy could confirm my observations.